# Orthogonal trajectories of unit circles centered on x-axis

Tags: integration, ordinary-differential-equations, plane-curves

Find ( $c$ is an arbitrary constant ) orthogonal trajectories of circles:

$$ (x-c)^2+ y^2= 1 $$

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: Got $ x=\int \sqrt{1/y^2-1} dy$

Comment: [Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4nGd6.gif) is an old cartoon I made that may be of interest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$\pm x+k=\int dy\sqrt{\frac1{y^2}-1}$$Put $y=\cos\theta$,$$\pm x+k=-\int \sin\theta\tan\theta~d\theta=-\int\frac{1-\cos^2\theta}{\cos\theta}d\theta\\=\sin\theta-\ln|\sec\theta+\tan\theta|\\=\sqrt{1-y^2}-\ln\left|1/y+\sqrt{1/y^2-1}\right|$$

Comment: How to  get $y=f(x)?$

Comment: @Narasimham I'm afraid an explicit expression for $y$ using elementary functions is not possible

Comment: How does $\pm$ sign work? Are there two solutions? We know it to be a tractrix.

Comment: @Narasimham The differential equation of the family of circles is $(y')^2=1/y^2-1\implies y'=\pm\sqrt{1/y^2-1}$

Comment: Is known as ...if $(y^{'}=\frac{dy}{dx} = \tan \phi ),\rightarrow  y = \cos \phi $

Comment: The situation here describes orthogonal net of unit circles and unit cusp radius tractrices.. all of them can be translated on x-axis.